# How do I fix the output of my analog sound equalizer?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, potentiometer, passive-filter

I'm new to electronics and I'm trying to build an analog sound equalizer with an TL071 as an amplifier. I have three different circuits for three different ranges (low frequencies, high frequencies and medium frequencies).
Each circuit for each range seems to be working fine, but the output (pin 6) doesn't change as expected. It should filter the signal according to the positions of each potentiometer.

The ampOp is in an adder configuration.

I tried messing with the resistors values, but to no effect. I know I can adjust each gain individually, but it didn't work.

Here's the full circuit (The last resistor is for measuring the output)

[image: Circuit made with Multisim]

How can I fix it?

Comment: To test an equaliser you should use a square wave (with no DC offset) instead of a sinewave as an input because a square wave contains many different frequency components. So you can see the effect better.

Comment: It is a tone controls circuit, not an equalizer. It cuts each frequencies range but does not boost.